# Loop through all folders within a folder and run command

Tags: bash, terminal, asset-catalog

I have a .png file that I saved as a .psd by mistake buried somewhere in an asset catalog. I figured out how to print the actual type of a file by `file -I /pathWithFileName` which on my desktop printed out 'Untitled-1.png: image/vnd.adobe.photoshop; charset=binary' which is correct as I intentionally made the mistake to test.

Now I want to run it on my entire asset catalog including all subfolder .imagesets but this does not quite do the trick:

```
find /mypath/Assets.xcassets/foldername/_foldername -type f -maxdepth 2 for i in *.imageset; file -I *.jpg ;
```

this does not work. Any ideas on how to loop through all Assets.xcassets folders and print out the file -I /pathWithFileName so I can see which image was saved wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `-path` option to match files ending in `.psd` in directories ending in `.imageset`. Then use the `-exec` option to run a command on the file.

```
find /mypath/Assets.xcassets/foldername/_foldername -type f -maxdepth 2 -path '*.imageset/*.psd' -exec file -I {} +
```

Comment: I observe that in the question text OP says he accidentally saved as .psd, but his example code seems to assume the mistaken extension to be .jpg.  This answer is geared toward the latter, though it should be obvious how to change the command to examine .psd files instead if that's what the OP really wants.